# mongoose self reference with own ObjectId throwing: cast to ObjectId failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using nodejs, mongoose and I trying to build a shema that contains a reference to itself via parent. Parent should be a reference to DataType.

```
var DataTypeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    label: { type: String, required: true },
    comment: { type: String },
    url: { type: String, required: true },
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DataType' },
    values: []
});

var DataType = mongoose.model('DataType', DataTypeSchema);
module.exports.DataType = DataType;
```

Every DataType has **own ID**(not generated by mongo) and I think this is a place where it causes problems. It throws me an error **cast to objectid failed for value "Number" at path "parent"**, where Number is object with ID "Number" already saved in DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the `parent` reference must match the type of the `_id` in the model it references.  So instead of `Schema.Types.ObjectId` it should be `String`:

```
...
parent: { type: String, ref: 'DataType' },
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. It is working and I can see it in DB. Only think is I don't have something like **ObjectID("Number")** only **"Number"**. I am quite new in MongoDB and also nodejs so I am not sure if it should look like that.

Comment: @user2748323 As long as "Number" provides a unique `_id` in the collection, that's completely fine and is correct.

Comment: Is there a way to get directly sort of **tree of objects** out of mongoose? What I would like to is instead of parent: _id get **parent: [Object]**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
parent: [ this ]
```

It works

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: This do not work property because it will not assign ObjectId to the objects from the list. I'm looking for other solution.